# Can't click "I am agree" button in Selenium with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, google-chrome

I try to write an automatic test in Selenium with NodeJS and I have a little problem.

First of all, my code:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require("selenium-webdriver");
async function example() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
  
}

example();
```

Every time i start my app with "node index", a new chrome/firefox app is opening and asking me if I am agree with cookies. I tried to go to settings or to connect my account and allow cookies anytime but if I start again my app, my settings are gone.

I think the solution is to click manually that "I am Agree" button with my code but I don't know how to do this. Can anybody help me, please?

How should I write the code to can click that agree button or what else I should try?

Comment: Did you try to set desired capabilities to accept cookies automaticly, if not try it

Comment: Do you encounter the "I am Agree" button accessing _`http://www.google.com`_?

Answer (score 0):

To click on `I agree` use the following `xpath` to identify the element

`await driver.findElement(By.xpth('//div[text()="I agree"]')).click()`

Your code will be

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require("selenium-webdriver");
async function example() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com');
    await driver.findElement(By.xpth('//div[text()="I agree"]')).click();
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
  
}

example();
```